# Additional configuration file(s) for Travis CI?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm currently contributing through a fork on GitHub to an open source project that uses Travis CI. Turning it on for the fork has been trivial, however I would like to add Slack notifications for our team without affecting the original `.travis.yaml`, so I was asking myself if it was possible to somehow define a secondary configuration file and add it to `.gitignore` (if that's ok with the original repo owners). Would this be possible? Is there any other way around the problem?

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-core/blob/2c0777dc9b289bb600d730650b41585b03f44b26/lib/travis/model/request.rb#L98) it seems like `.travis.yml` is hard-coded and there's no way to override that or have a secondary file, is it?

Comment: You are correct: there is *no* way of using a file other than `./.travis.yml`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess I'll try to propose the feature. Thanks!